# Access CosmosDB Data from Azure App Service by using managed identity (Failed)

Tags: python, terraform, azure-web-app-service, azure-cosmosdb, azure-managed-identity

A FastAPI-based API written in Python has been deployed as an Azure App Service. The API needs to read and write data from CosmosDB, and I attempted to use Managed Identity for this purpose, but encountered an error, stating `Unrecognized credential type`

These are the key steps that I took towards that goal

**Step One**: I used Terraform to configure the managed identity for Azure App Service, and assigned the 'contributor' role to the identity so that it can access and write data to CosmosDB. The role assignment was carried out in the file where the Azure App Service is provisioned.

```
  resource "azurerm_linux_web_app" "this" {
  name     = var.appname
  location = var.location
  resource_group_name = var.rg_name
  service_plan_id = azurerm_service_plan.this.id


  app_settings = {
    "PROD"                               = false
    "DOCKER_ENABLE_CI"                   = true
    "DOCKER_REGISTRY_SERVER_URL"         = data.azurerm_container_registry.this.login_server
    "WEBSITE_HTTPLOGGING_RETENTION_DAYS" = "30"
    "WEBSITE_ENABLE_APP_SERVICE_STORAGE" = false
  }

  lifecycle {
    ignore_changes = [
      app_settings["WEBSITE_HTTPLOGGING_RETENTION_DAYS"]
    ]
  }

  https_only = true
  
  identity {
    type = "SystemAssigned"
  }

data "azurerm_cosmosdb_account" "this" {
  name                = var.cosmosdb_account_name
  resource_group_name = var.cosmosdb_resource_group_name
}

// built-in role that allow the app-service to read and write to an Azure Cosmos DB
resource "azurerm_role_assignment" "cosmosdbContributor" {
  scope              = data.azurerm_cosmosdb_account.this.id
  principal_id       = azurerm_linux_web_app.this.identity.0.principal_id
  role_definition_name = "Contributor"
}
```

**Step Two**: I used the managed identity library to fetch the necessary credentials in the Python code.

```
from azure.identity import ManagedIdentityCredential
from azure.cosmos.cosmos_client import CosmosClient
client = CosmosClient(get_endpoint(),credential=ManagedIdentityCredential())
client = self._get_or_create_client()
database = client.get_database_client(DB_NAME)
container = database.get_container_client(CONTAINER_NAME)
container.query_items(query)
```

I received the following error when running the code locally and from Azure (the error can be viewed from the Log stream of the Azure App Service):

```
raise TypeError(
TypeError: Unrecognized credential type. Please supply the master key as str, or a dictionary or resource tokens, or a list of permissions.
```

Any help or discussion is welcome

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the Python SDK, you can directly do this ,check the sample [here](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-python/blob/main/sdk/cosmos/azure-cosmos/samples/access_cosmos_with_aad.py)

```
aad_credentials = ClientSecretCredential(
    tenant_id="<azure-ad-tenant-id>",
    client_id="<client-application-id>",
    client_secret="<client-application-secret>")
client = CosmosClient("<account-endpoint>", aad_credentials)
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. I was using the method you mentioned previously, however, I would prefer not to use keys or secrets. Managed identity appears to be a suitable solution, however, I am currently experiencing difficulty in getting it to function properly. Could you please assist me in understanding why it is not working?

Comment: are you getting the same error?

Comment: Hi Sajeetharan, my apologies for the unclear explanation. No, it was working fine and I've been using this method for 2 years and it works just fine. However, we want to get rid of all the keys as we have way too many to manage. It seems that managed identity is an ideal solution for this.